# Webpack,Karma test Babel Missing class properties transform

Tags: reactjs, webpack, karma-runner, babeljs

Hi I am running a karma test on a React-Redux app and getting error:

```
Missing class properties transform
```

Ie error with static keyword as in

```
static propTypes
```

This only happens when running npm test with karma not with running the actual app.
I downloaded "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties":"^6.11.5", and included in my webpack.config.js as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/client/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          plugins: [,
            [
              'react-transform', {
                transforms: [{
                  transform: ['react-transform-hmr',
                  'transform-class-properties']
                  imports: ['react'],
                  locals: ['module']
                }, {
                  transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
                  imports: ['react', 'redbox-react']
                }]
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'raw']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

I am still getting same error.
Please let me know what is missing, thanks.
This is my package.json file just in case

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties":"^6.11.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.15.1",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^1.4.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.4.0",
    "expect": "^1.10.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.24",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.3.2",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^1.0.0",
    "nock": "^2.18.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "redux-slider-monitor":"1.0.7",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.0",
    "redbox-react": "^1.0.6",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-chart-monitor":"1.4.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "0.0.4",
    "webpack": "^1.9.10",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-isomorphic-tools": "^0.8.8"
  },
```